# OpenTelemetry custom traceId addition

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I am using the otel java agent above multimple spring boot microservices.

I want to achieve a simple scenario. Let's suppose that my system is called system A. An arbitrary System B, which is probably not based on otel, makes a request to my system with a generated traceId of it's own attached to request headers. I want somehow to keep logging this traceId inside my distributed logging.

What i have tried so far :

**Option 1** -> Write an extension for the java agent and add a customIdGenerator which reads the id produced from System B from a flat source. [traceId should be 32d long, the traceId from System b cannot guarantee that].

```
public class DemoIdGenerator implements IdGenerator {
  private static final AtomicLong traceId = new AtomicLong(0);
  private static final AtomicLong spanId = new AtomicLong(0);

  @Override
  public String generateSpanId() {
    return String.format("%016d", spanId.incrementAndGet());
  }

  // has to be 32d
  @Override
  public String generateTraceId() {
    return String.format("%032d", traceId.incrementAndGet());
  }
}
```

**Option 2** -> Write a custom SpanProcessor, add the id as span attribute and propagate the attribute while overriding the onStart(..) SpanProcessor method. - [cannot retrieve attributes since spans are immutable].

```
public class DemoSpanProcessor implements SpanProcessor {
  @Override
  public void onStart(Context parentContext, ReadWriteSpan span) {
    // cannot retrieve parent context span attributes
    span.setAttribute("parent_external_id", "id_from_parent");
  }
...
}
```

Another problem is that when i will try to attach SpanContext to logger pattern, the context does not contain span attributes either. so I can't use them for logging with OpenTelemtryAppender.

```
final class AutoValue_ImmutableSpanContext extends ImmutableSpanContext {
    private final String traceId;
    private final String spanId;
    private final TraceFlags traceFlags;
    private final TraceState traceState;
    private final boolean remote;
    private final boolean valid;
...
```

Any idea? Has anyone tried to achieve something similar using **Baggage** interface maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suitable way using Baggage api propagation. I wrote a custom span processor so i achieved propagating custom attributes through Baggage.current() and populate them on spans while overriding the onStart() method of span processor.

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/7396#discussioncomment-4539912